# Joomla 3.8 e JQuery - Não funciona

Tags: jquery, joomla

Olá!
Procurei em tudo que foi canto e não encontrei um passo a passo de como usar JQuery no Joomla 3.8.
Estou criando um módulo e eu gostaria de usar JQuery.

Eu fiz isso aqui:

1 - download do jquery-3.3.1.js e coloquei na pasta: /modules/mod_mymodule/js

2. Lendo a documentação do Joomla, eu adicionei as seguintes linhas no meu arquivo modules/mod_mymodule/mod_mymodule.php file:

   ```
   JHtml::script(JURI::base() . 'js/jquery-3.3.1.js');
   Jhtml::_('jquery.framework');
   Jhtml::_('jquery.ui');
   ```
3. No final da página do meu arquivo default.php eu adicionei isso:

   ```
   <?php
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
   $document->addScriptDeclaration('
       window.event("domready", function() {
           alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
       });
   ');
   ?>
   ```

Deveria mostrar uma janela de alerta quando a página é carregada mas não funciona. O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Ten tente trocar `window.event("domready", function() {
        alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
    });` por `$(function() {
        alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
    });`

Comment: Tb não acontece nada fazendo desse jeito.

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta, é para uma versão mais antiga do Joomla, mas acredito que possa funcionar para vc! Tem duas opções de como fazer isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351739/inserindo-javascript-na-header-do-joomla-2-5-8/351849#351849

Answer (score -1):

Para evitar conflito com as bibliotecas do Joomla você deve usar o `JQuery` com o um formato diferente. Em vez de usar o `$` para buscar os `ID`, `CLASS`, etc, você deve usar o nome `jQuery`:

```
var variavel = jQuery("#id_do_elemento_html").val();
```

Nessa página (docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_Map) vc vai encontrar um exemplo de como adicionar um mapa, aqui o autor faz uso do JQuery da maneira como eu mostrei acima. Essa é uma página oficial do Joomla

Eu faço assim e sempre funciona.

Comment: Pode ser a solução, mas seria interessante você explicar para o autor da pergunta, com apoio de documentação oficial, o do porque essa é a saída: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks#jQuery_JavaScript_Framework

Comment: Nessa página (https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_Map) vc vai encontrar um exemplo de como adicionar um mapa, aqui o autor faz uso do JQuery da maneira como eu mostrei acima. Essa é uma página oficial do Joomla.

Comment: Em baixo da resposta tem três botões `compartilhar editar sinalizar`. Clique em `editar` e de uma caprichada na resposta. Pois assim que a editar, ela vai para a página principal obtendo mais visibilidade e ganhando a possibilidade de angariar alguns up votes.