# Inserindo javascript na header do joomla 2.5.8

Tags: javascript, header, joomla

Muitos anos que não mexo em joomla e um cliente antigo me pediu para inserir um javascript na header do site. Como faço isso?
A versão do joomla é 2.5.8

O código da página principal é

```
<?php    
    /* Design by VTEM http://www.vtem.net  All Rights Reserved */    
    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );    
    JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);    
    include_once(JPATH_ROOT . "/templates/" . $this->template . '/vtemtools/default.php');    
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">    
    <?php    
    include_once(JPATH_ROOT."/templates/".$this->template.'/vtemtools/css_var.php');
    ?>

    <body id="vtem" class="<?php echo css_browser_selector().' '.$pageoption.' '.$pageview.' template-'.$TemplateStyle.' logo-'.$logo;?>">    
      <div id="vt_body_wrapper">    
          <div id="vt_main_wrapper">    
        <div id="vt_wrapper" class="clearfix">

          <!-- /////////////////// HEADER LAYOUT ///////////////////////////////-->    
          <div id="vt_header_section" class="vt_header_section clearfix">      
                      <div id="vt_drawer_head_top" class="vt_drawer_head_top clearfix">      
                     <?php if ($this->countModules('drawer1 + drawer2 + drawer3 + drawer4 + drawer5 + drawer6 ')) : ?>    
                          <div class="vt_wrapper_drawer clearfix">    
                          <div class="vt_section clearfix">    
                             <div id="vt_drawer" class="vt_drawer clearfix">    
                                  <?php echo VTEMShowModule('drawer', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                             </div>    
                           </div>      
                          </div>    
                     <?php endif;?>                        

                        <div class="vt_wrapper_header clearfix">    
                        <div class="vt_section clearfix"> 
                             <div id="vt_header" class="vt_header clearfix">    
                                  <?php echo VTEMShowModule('header', 'vt_xhtml', 6, 'header1', 'header2');?>    
                             </div>    
                         </div>        
                         </div>    
                      </div>   

                      <?php if ($this->countModules('top1 + top2 + top3 + top4 + top5 + top6 ')) : ?>    
                        <div class="vt_wrapper_top clearfix">    
                         <div id="vt_top" class="vt_top clearfix">    
                              <?php echo VTEMShowModule('top', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                         </div>    
                         </div>    
                     <?php endif;?>  
          </div>

           <!-- /////////////////// MAIN LAYOUT ///////////////////////////////-->

           <div id="vt_main_section" class="vt_main_section clearfix">    
               <?php if ($this->countModules('showcase1 + showcase2 + showcase3 + showcase4 + showcase5 + showcase6 ')) : ?>    
                  <div class="vt_wrapper_showcase clearfix">    
                  <div class="vt_section clearfix">      
                     <div id="vt_showcase" class="vt_showcase clearfix">    
                          <?php echo VTEMShowModule('showcase', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                          <div class="clr"></div>        
                     </div>    
                   </div>      
                   </div>    
               <?php endif; ?>               

             <?php if ($this->countModules('feature1 + feature2 + feature3 + feature4 + feature5 + feature6 ')) : ?>    
                      <div class="vt_wrapper_feature clearfix">    
                      <div class="vt_section clearfix">    
                         <div id="vt_feature" class="vt_feature clearfix">    
                              <?php echo VTEMShowModule('feature', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                              <div class="clr"></div>    
                         </div>      
                       </div>      
                      </div>      
              <?php endif;?>

                <div id="vt_main_inside" class="clearfix">    
                <div class="vt_section clearfix">    
                  <div id="vt_main_contaner" class="clearfix">    
                  <?php if(($pageview == "wrapper") || ($Layout == "wf")) :    
                           echo '<div id="vt_full">';    
                                if($SystemMessages == 1) :    
                                   echo '<jdoc:include type="message" />';    
                                endif;    
                           echo $component.'</div>';

                        else : // LEFT-BODY_RIGHT ////////////////

                                if($this->countModules('left')) :    
                                    echo '<div id="vt_nav_left" class="vt_auto_cols '.$navleft.' '.$leftfloat.'">'.$modleft.'</div>';    
                                endif;    
                                    echo '<div id="vt_main_com" class="vt_auto_cols '.$contentwidth.' '.$bodyfloat.'">    
                                             <div class="vt_component_inside">';    
                                                 if($SystemMessages == 1) :    
                                                    echo '<jdoc:include type="message" />';    
                                                 endif;    
                                                    echo $component;    
                                                 if ($this->countModules('inset1 + inset2')) :    
                                                    echo '<div id="vt_inset" class="vt_inset clearfix">'.VTEMShowModule('inset', 'vt_xhtml', 2).'</div>';    
                                                 endif;    
                                   echo ' </div>    
                                        </div>';    
                                if($this->countModules('right')) :    
                                   echo '<div id="vt_nav_right" class="vt_auto_cols '.$navright .' '. $rightfloat.'">'.$modright.'</div>';    
                                endif;

                            // END LEFT-BODY_RIGHT ///////////////////////////    
                        endif; ?>    
             </div>     

            <?php if ($this->countModules('utility1 + utility2 + utility3 + utility4 + utility5 + utility6 ')) : ?>    
               <div class="vt_wrapper_utility clearfix">    
               <div class="vt_section clearfix">    
                 <div id="vt_utility" class="vt_utility clearfix">    
                        <?php echo VTEMShowModule('utility', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                        <div class="clr"></div>    
                </div>    
                </div>    
               </div>      
            <?php endif; ?>   

            <?php if ($this->countModules('bottom1 + bottom2 + bottom3 + bottom4 + bottom5 + bottom6 ')) : ?>    
               <div class="vt_wrapper_bottom clearfix">      
                 <div id="vt_bottom" class="vt_bottom clearfix">    
                          <?php echo VTEMShowModule('bottom', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                          <div class="clr"></div>    
                 </div>    
               </div>      
            <?php endif; ?>      
          </div>   
         </div>    
        </div>             

          <!-- /////////////////// FOOTER LAYOUT ///////////////////////////-->  

      <div id="vt_footer_section" class="vt_footer_section clearfix">    
          <div class="vt_section clearfix">    
            <div id="vt_wapper_footer">    
               <?php if ($this->countModules('footer1 + footer2 + footer3 + footer4 + footer5 + footer6 ')) : ?>    
                     <div id="vt_footer" class="vt_footer clearfix">    
                            <?php echo VTEMShowModule('footer', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                            <div class="clr"></div>    
                    </div>    
               <?php endif; ?>

               <div class="wapper_copyright_gotop clearfix">    
               <?php if ($this->countModules('copyright1 + copyright2 + copyright3 + copyright4 + copyright5 + copyright6 ')) : ?>    
                     <div id="vt_copyright" class="vt_copyright clearfix">    
                            <?php echo VTEMShowModule('copyright', 'vt_xhtml', 6);?>    
                            <?php if($totop) echo '<div id="gotop"><p><a href="#vtem" title="Back to Top"><span>Go Top</span></a></p></div>';?>    
                     </div>    
               <?php endif; ?>    
               <div class="clr"></div>    
                <?php echo $vtcopyright;?>    
               </div>    
           </div>    
          </div>       
         </div>    
       </div>         
      </div>  
    </div>      
    <?php include_once(JPATH_ROOT . "/templates/" . $this->template . '/vtemtools/debug.php');?>    
   </body>    
</html>
```

O script seria esse aqui:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="PrivallyApp" src="https://app.privally.io/app.js" pid="3738be7e-70997729" async></script>
```

Depois ainda preciso jogar um outro script no corpo de uma página.

Comment: Vc quer esse código em todas as páginas ou apenas em alguma página em específico?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que pela área do Administrador talvez seja ainda mais fácil de resolver isso. Mas pode depender um pouco do seu tema... Nesse exemplo com esse tema tinha a tag `<head>` no `.php` ai facilitou.

Vou te dar duas opções, uma usando a tag `<script>` e a outra colocando o arquivo `.js` em uma pasta junto dos outros `.js` do tema.

**Depois de logar na área do adm vai na sessão de Temas**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora clica nesse link para entrar nas opções de customização do tema**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora clica no link referente a main page do seu tema**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Vai abrir uma página semelhante a essa onde vc pode inserir o link do script**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Pronto seu scriot vai aparecer assim na sua página**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Opção 2

Se o seu tema tiver uma chamada para os scripts vc pode incluir o arquivo .js direto na página e chamar na Main Page
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No browser vai ficar assim **repare no caminha da sua página de .JS ai no eu tema!**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### DICA

**Esse seria um caminho próximo do que vc deve ter ai para a pasta dos `.JS`**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E esse é o caminho da Main Page que vc tem que alterar, caso quera acessa-lo na mão**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu pela dica e atenção irmão, mas o tema que o meu cliente usa não apresenta a Head e nem tem para fazer a segunda opção. :(

Comment: @AlessandroRamos então põem direto ali no php e faz um teste, pois a tag script não precisa ser dentro do head